# using Bundle object to parse JSONobject Fragment to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

i am using `Bundle` object to parse `jsonobject` one fragment to another `fragment`.but when running App it crash..can any one help me....

**Fragment 1**

after getting my jsonobject using `Async` task using button i open the my second Fragment

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG,"More button clicked");
        Fragment_account_details fragment = new Fragment_account_details();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String accountDetails = name_value_list.toString();
        bundle.putString("accountDetails", accountDetails);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment.newInstance(),
                fragment.TAG).commit();
    };
```

**Fragment 2**

```
public class Fragment_account_details extends Fragment {

    TextView name, officePhone,fax,email;

    public static Fragment_account_details newInstance() {
        return new Fragment_account_details();
    }

    public final static String TAG = Fragment_account_details.class
            .getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_details, container,false);

        name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        fax = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_fax);
        email = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_email);

        String accountDetails = getArguments().getString("accountDetails");


        return rootView;


    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
12-09 11:18:22.291: D/Fragment_Entry_Account(1486): More button clicked
12-09 11:18:22.307: D/AndroidRuntime(1486): Shutting down VM
12-09 11:18:22.307: W/dalvikvm(1486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cacb20)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): Process: com.wakensys.sugercrm_wakensys, PID: 1486
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.wakensys.sugercrm_wakensys.fragments.Fragment_account_details.onCreateView(Fragment_account_details.java:41)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-09 11:18:22.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is name_value_list??

Comment: @pramod-yadavit is my `JSONObject`

Comment: are you sure its not null because you are getting nullpointer exception when you are trying to retrieve it try to print and see that its not null

Comment: @pramod-yadav i checked it as you said.. but it shows data in logcat..its not null

Comment: after showing data app will crash same as before

Comment: which is the 41 line of your Fragment_account_details?

Comment: its this String `String accountDetails = getArguments().getString("accountDetails");`

Comment: instead of fragment.newInstance() in your transaction use Fragment_account_details.newInstance()

Comment: app work without `String accountDetails = getArguments().getString("accountDetails");` this in fragment 2.